# Perl command line replace for unicode

Tags: regex, bash, perl, unicode

I am trying to replace every word (stored in a tmp file called `_id`) with a number using shell script. It works fine except for unicode words, for which a number is generated but replacement using Perl does not work. The bash code under question is as below:

```
x=0
for id in `cat _id`; do
    echo $x $id
    perl -p -i -e "s/\b$id\b/$x/g" x_graph.dot
    x=$(($x + 1))
done
```

Can someone please point out to where the bug is?

Comment: Please provide the necessary data to demonstrate the problem. For example, reduce `_id` and `x_graph.dot` to one line each, then provide the output of `od -t x1 _id x_graph.dot`.

Comment: Unicode is a bit more complex than you seem to believe.  Putting aside considerations like normalization, if you replace the `-e` in the perl command line with `-E` then you'll at least enable the "unicode strings" feature in modern version of perl.  But that barely scratches the surface.

Comment: I suspect the problem is the use of `\b` on encoded text

Comment: I don't think _any_ regex engine handles word boundary's correctly when it comes to Unicode. You'd have to roll your own word boundary in that case.

Comment: Thanks @ikegami it did require removing word boundary.

Comment: Don't fix an encoding problem by removing `\b`!!! Now you have two problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have `é` (U+00E9) encoded using UTF-8: `C3 A9`. Since you don't do any decoding, you obtain the string that's produced by `"\xC3\xA9"`.

Regular expressions —or rather `\b`, `\w`, `\d`, etc— expect the input to be Unicode Code Points, which means you are effectively providing [U+00C3](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00C3/index.htm) and [U+00A9](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00A9/index.htm) instead of U+00E9. U+00C3 is a word character, but U+00A9 isn't, so the second `\b` doesn't match where it's expected to match.

So you need to decode your inputs and encode your outputs. `-C` provides a convenient way of doing that for UTF-8.

```
perl -i -CSDA -pe'
   BEGIN {
      ($id, $x) = splice(@ARGV, 0, 2);
      die "Bad id" if $id !~ /^\w(?:.*\w)?\z/s;
   }

   s/\b\Q$id\E\b/$x/g
' "$id" "$x" x_graph.dot
```

Notes:

- By using command-line arguments to pass the arguments, I fixed an injection error.
- The use of `\b` assumes that `$id` will always start with a `\w` char and always end with a `\w` char, so I added a check to verify that assumption.
- By using `\Q..\E` to convert the id into a regex pattern, I fixed an injection error.

---

Test:

```
$ printf "é\n" >_id

$ printf "[é]\n" >x_graph.dot

$ x=0

$ id=`cat _id`

$ perl -i -CSDA -pe'
   BEGIN {
      ($id, $x) = splice(@ARGV, 0, 2);
      die "Bad id" if $id !~ /^\w(?:.*\w)?\z/s;
   }

   s/\b\Q$id\E\b/$x/g
' "$id" "$x" x_graph.dot

$ cat x_graph.dot
[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

See [perldoc perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

> #### `-C` [number/list]
>
> The `-C` flag controls some of the Perl Unicode features:
>
> ```
> I     1   STDIN is assumed to be in UTF-8
> O     2   STDOUT will be in UTF-8
> E     4   STDERR will be in UTF-8
> S     7   I + O + E
> i     8   UTF-8 is the default PerlIO layer for input streams
> o    16   UTF-8 is the default PerlIO layer for output streams
> D    24   i + o
> A    32   the @ARGV elements are expected to be strings encoded
>           in UTF-8
> ```

So, at the very least, you'd want `perl -COi`, but `perl -CSD` looks tidier.

In addition, you may want to use

> `u`  match according to Unicode rules

with your `s///`. Or, write:

`perl -CSD -Mutf8 -Mfeature=unicode_strings -p -i -e "s/\b$id\b/$x/g" x_graph.dot`

Note the use of single quotation marks instead of double so as to avoid unintended interpolation.

Comment: Thank you! I also needed to remove `\b` (word boundaries) to get it to work. Which is not really desirable as I would have linked to have it working with word boundaries.

Comment: Since `$id` is a shell variable, not a perl variable, you can't enclose it in single quotes like that.

Comment: If you're going to remove the `\b`, then you don't need to do any of those other changes!!!

Answer (score 3):

1. Add `-Mutf8`(equivalent of [`use utf8;`](https://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html)): This will enable UTF-8 in source code (`-e` one-liner in your case).
2. Add `-CSDA`: This will make `perl` use UTF-8 as default layer for input and output streams.

The following test produced desired result under `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

```
echo "a ó b" > z.txt
id=ó
x=ń
perl -CD -Mutf8 -p -i -e "s/\b$id\b/$x/g" z.txt
cat z.txt
```

[`man perlrun`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html)

> -C [number/list]
>   The -C flag controls some of the Perl Unicode features.
>   …
>   S  8 I + O + E  [ STDIN is assumed to be in UTF-8, STDOUT and STDERR will be in UTF-8]
>   D 24 i + o [ UTF-8 is the default PerlIO layer for input and output streams]
>   A 32 the @ARGV elements are expected to be strings encoded
>                 in UTF-8

Comment: @sinan-Ünür Thank for the bugfix in explanations :-)